# Getting loopback error while mocking api response through wiremock

Tags: java, spring, wiremock

I’m getting the following error while mocking response using wiremock.

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Request on loopback from external IP: "Request on loopback from external IP

## Request on loopback from external IP

---

**Description: Your request is prohibited because the request is on loopback from external IP.**

---

I’m working with spring Using  wiremock version 2.35.0 with junit 5

Please help

I tried with localhost. It’s giving error - Unknown hostname. I checked in the DNS entry it’s present. Also I have checked that I’m able to access localhost on my machine

Comment: Please provide a code sample that demonstrates where you think the error is occurring

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.